# BigSur open command does not handle message:// URLs anymore, workarounds?

Tags: url, uri, macos-big-sur, macos-mail-app

In macOS you can obtain ([explained here how](https://thesweetsetup.com/working-email-urls-macos/#:%7E:text=Select%20the%20message%20for%20which,direct%20message%20link%20to%20appear.)) the URL to a specific email. So that if you click to the that URL, or you paste it into a browser search bar, that specific email will open in Mail.app.

Such a URL looks like this `message://<CALoR5A+vANPG9eCcHRHnO@mail.gmail.com>`

In Catalina I could use the command `open` to reach such a URL from the command line, by typing

`open -a "Mail.app" "message://<CALoR5A+vANPG9eCcHRHnO@mail.gmail.com>"`

But with BigSur if I try that I get the following error

```
The file /Users/macbook/message:/<CALoR5A+vANPG9eCcHRHnO@mail.gmail.com> does not exist.
```

This behavior seems to be related to a [bug in BigSur](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663762).

## Two question

1. Do you know if the `open` command can still be used for that task somehow?
2. Alternatively, I am looking for a workaround. It must be possible to achieve the behavior I am expecting because if you past a `message://` URL in Chrome, Safari or in a rich text editor which supports hyperlinks, it is correctly handled.

I have tried, unsuccessfully many approaches.

### Swift script

```
import AppKit
NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(string: "message://<CALoR5A+vANPG9eCcHRHnO@mail.gmail.com>")!)
```

The URL is `nil`.

### Apple Script

```
tell application "Mail"
    activate
    open location "message://<CALoR5A+vANPG9eCcHRHnO@mail.gmail.com>"
end tell
```

I am not sure if the above code would have worked in Catalina, I just know that in my case it just opens the Mail app without doing anything else.

### Using Chrome

If you paste a `message://` URL in Chrome it asks you to confirm that you want to open it in the Mail app. This can be overridden with the following command:
`defaults write com.google.Chrome URLWhitelist -array 'message://*'`

Asking Chrome to open a URL for you looks like a easier task, but still the command
`open -a "Google Chrome" "message://<CALoR5A+vANPG9eCcHRHnO@mail.gmail.com>"`
fails with an error similar to the one shown before:

```
LoR5A+vANPG9eCcHRHnO@mail.gmail.com>"
The file /Users/macbook/message:/<CALoR5A+vANPG9eCcHRHnO@mail.gmail.com> does not exist.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason why the `open` command does not work anymore: the angular brackets need to be escaped.

The following command does not work

```
open -a "Google Chrome.app" "message:<CALoR5A+vANPG9eCcHRHnO_fNTrzgbMpX666oBGxHWsRaXb5@mail.gmail.com>"
```

The following one opens the Mail app, which will complain that the URL is broken

```
open -a "Google Chrome.app" "message:CALoR5A+vANPG9eCcHRHnO_fNTrzgbMpX666oBGxHWsRaXb5@mail.gmail.com>"
```

Finally, by escaping the URL, it works:

```
open -a "Google Chrome.app" "message:%3CCALoR5A%2BvANPG9eCcHRHnO_fNTrzgbMpX666oBGxHWsRaXb5%40mail.gmail.com%3E"
```

Note, you can make the URL start with `message:` or `message://`, it does not matter.